# CMake file won't create target

Tags: cmake

I have a question related to CMakeLists.

I have a cmake file in which I included some .c and some .asm files. I then wanted to create an executable with these files. Then I run cmake and make and it says "Built target exeName" however I cannot find 'exeName' on my computer. Should I do something else or is there a problem with the script?

Comment: Please, search for compiled binary file in your build directory, show your file CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be there. In my binary dir I have some CMakeFiles/exe_name.dir which contains some other files but not the binary I am expecting.

Comment: Try `make VERBOSE=1 exe_name` to see exact command line that is being run. There you can find `-o path/to/your/exe`.